# Create Postgres database with R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have quite a few data sets in `.rds` files that I would like to share with some analysts who who use statistical software other than R (**gasp**), and I would like to dump them into a PostgreSQL database.  I noticed this line in `?src_postgres` that suggests that Postgres databases can be created through `dplyr`:

```
Arguments
... 
src     a postgres src created with src_postgres.
```

(though maybe this is referring to a database connection not the database itself).  I've also searched documentation for the package `RPostgreSQL` to find a way to create an empty database without luck.

I know that SQLite databases are easy to create with `dplyr::src_sqlite(...,create=TRUE)`, but SQLite lacks the ability to store a good deal of the meta-data that I'm hoping to preserve.

Comment: this refers to a data connection

Comment: what sort of meta data are you hoping to preserve?

Comment: Look into the [RODBC](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html) package which connects to all major databases. I've used it with MS Access, SQL Server, and MySQL. You will have to first install the PostgreSQL ODBC driver. And as aside, I recommend you design your database outside of programming languages such as R, Python, PHP, etc. Use code to interact with databases, never to build them. You could even download a free PostgreSQL web console and upload datasets with csv, txt, xml, sql files.

Comment: dates and factors (enum).  In particular, I would like to keep the ordering of factor levels.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait.  I hadn't thought about RODBC...